# Convert string to long in groovy

Tags: groovy

Please let me know how can I convert the string "4000.00" from string to Long 4000 in groovy.

I used Long.valueOf("4000.00") and Long.parselong("4000.00") but give error.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4000.00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"4000.00"` is a decimal number, so it cannot be parsed as a long. You can parse it as a double and then convert to long:

```
long value = Double.valueOf("4000.00").longValue()

//or

long value = (long) Double.parseDouble("4000.00")
```